# PHP Hydrator\ClassMethodsHydrator underscore replacing to camelCase which cause error

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I am using doctrine 2 and my entity has variables set like:

```
     /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    protected $phone_number;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    protected $e_mail;
```

Now i want to fill this variables from array using Hydrator like this:

```
public function fromArray($values)
    {
        $hydrator = new \Hydrator\ClassMethodsHydrator();
        $hydrator->hydrate($values, $this);
    }
```

But after using this function i get error becuase Hydrator tries to call **setphoneNumber()** instead of **setPhone_number()** ...

Can you help me how to achieve my goal instead of changing underscores to camelCase?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
 /**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", name="phone_number")
 */
protected $phoneNumber;
```

Doctrine would rename your phoneNumber into phone_number anyway when creating your database schema, but by using the name attribute in \Column or \Table Definition you can make sure your name is used.

So in your *database table column* it's: phone_number

Your *entity attribute* is called: phoneNumber

So this will usually end up in *setPhoneNumber* for your *setters* which is fine.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This works, but i am little bit worried if it is a propper way to do it. Because entity represents table and object variable represents column and i didnt want to mess it up with having different names for "same thing"

Comment: You can easily accept the answer - this is the proper way to do it. Because even if it feels like the same thing - it isn't! One is your table definition, the other is your entity definition and according to ORM concepts this isn't the same. You will see a lot of people struggling with this difference when it comes to SELECTS in DQL vs SQL e.g.